# WPF Entity Framework binding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I'm following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574514) and trying to implement `Data Binding` using an `Editable ComboBox` instead of the `DataGrid` demonstrated in the tutorial.
The only problem I encounter is that I cannot add a new item to the DB that way.
This is how I load the data:

```
    private DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource productViewSource =
            ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("productViewSource")));

        db.Product.Load();

        productViewSource.Source = db.Product.Local;
    }
```

and in a `Button_Click` event I tried the following methods without success:

```
    db.Product.Add(new Product() { ProductCode = "", Description = "" });
    db.Product.Load();
    productViewSource.Source = db.Product.Local;
    productComboBox.Items.Refresh();
    productViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToLast();
```

and:

```
    ListCollectionView lcv = productComboBox.ItemsSource as ListCollectionView;
    lcv.AddNewItem(new Product() { ProductCode = "", Description = "" });
    lcv.MoveCurrentToLast();
```

Using the `DataGrid` provided by the default `DataSource` template works as expected by adding a new item on the empty bottom row of the grid.
Please advise.

Comment: So Product is added but it\`s fields are empty? It\`s hard to diagnose the problem without the code that\`s changing fields, i.e. `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be calling `SaveChanges` on your data context object anywhere. I would have thought that your code should look more like this:

```
db.Product.Add(new Product() { ProductCode = "", Description = "" });
db.SaveChanges();
```

Please see the [Add/Attach and Entity States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) page on MSDN for more help with adding entities in the Entity Framework.

Comment: Tried it but for some reason the `ProductCode` and `Description` values remain empty even if I change their values in the ComboBox and call `SaveChanges` again

Comment: *for some reason*... try debugging your code to find out what reason. I can't help you if you can't help you.